# Silex + Nginx 1.8 - 404 on routes

Tags: php, nginx, silex

I've updated my Nginx version to 1.8. I also use php5-fpm. Everything was fine until Nginx update (from version 1.2.1).

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gazeta.ovh file:
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/gazeta.ovh/web;
  index index.php;

  server_name gazeta.ovh;

  charset utf-8;

  location = / {
    try_files @site @site;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @site;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
  }

  location @site {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params file:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

I've got 2 routes:

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) { return 'route 1' });
$app->get('/test', function() use ($app) { return 'route 2' });
```

Route / works fine. But when I try to get /test route, I get 404 error from nginx:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Nginx access log shows 404 error "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "curl/7.35.0"

However, trying to access gazeta.ovh/index.php/test works.

What should I change to get it work? I've tried to add SCRIPT_FILENAME param, but with no success. I've tried:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
```

Any help appreciated:)

EDIT:

Ok, fixed it by changing domain config to:

```
server {
  server_name *.gazeta.ovh;
  return 301 $scheme://gazeta.ovh$request_uri;
}

  server {

  listen 80;
  root /var/www/gazeta.ovh/web;
  index index.php;

  server_name gazeta.ovh;

  charset utf-8;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```